# Copy C# DataTable and convert all values to string

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, system.data.datatable

I have a `DataTable` with columns of different types. What I want is a `DataTable` that has the same column names but all values are strings. That is, if this is the first:

```
Name   Age
-----------
John   31
Alice  27
Marge  45
```

where Name is a `String` column and Age is an `Int32` column, what I want is:

```
Name   Age
-----------
John   31
Alice  27
Marge  45
```

where Name and Age are *both* string columns. The output table must contain the same values as the input table but every value must be converted to a string. Can anyone provide any insight on how one might go about doing this? I thought about maybe doing something like

```
foreach (DataColumn col in inputTable.Columns)
{
    outputTable.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, typeof(string));

    foreach (DataRow row in inputTable.Rows)
    {
        ...??
    }
}
```

Or perhaps there is a better or more efficient approach? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't modify a column type in `DataTable` if already has records. You can [`Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) DataTable and then modify column type in each column of cloned table. Later you can import rows.

```
DataTable dtClone = dt.Clone(); //just copy structure, no data
for (int i = 0; i < dtClone.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (dtClone.Columns[i].DataType != typeof(string))
        dtClone.Columns[i].DataType = typeof(string);
}

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    dtClone.ImportRow(dr);
}
```

`dtClone` will have every column as of string and all the data from original table `dt`

Comment: Thanks for your response. This this like calling `ToString()` on the values behind the scenes? I thought `ImportRow` preserved the original data types, in which case wouldn't this give a type error?

Comment: @Alex, no, ImportRow just import data and fits it in the available container. I have tried the above code in VS and it works

Comment: I'm getting that all of the columns are now string type but the `MaxLength` property for each `DataColumn` is -1. Shouldn't that always be >=0 for string columns?

Comment: @Alex, `MaxLength -1` indicates that the column can store any length of string. It is usually used for typed datasets, where you can specify its length to be same as database column length.

Comment: It doesn't specify the maximum length of current string in the column

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, @Habib. Your method of getting the `DataTable` works great and I appreciate your clarification of the `MaxLength` property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a built in method called toString().

```
foreach (DataColumn col in inputTable.Columns)
{
outputTable.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, typeof(string));

foreach (DataRow row in inputTable.Rows)
{
outputTable.Columns.Add(row.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `outputTable.Rows.Add(row.ToString())` instead of `Columns.Add`?

Answer (score 0):

in this code, you can convert whole dataset in to one string.

```
string ConvertDatasetToString(DataSet Ds)
{
    string OUT = "";
    for (int t = 0; t < Ds.Tables.Count; t++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < Ds.Tables[t].Rows.Count; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < Ds.Tables[t].Columns.Count; c++)
            {
                string s = Ds.Tables[t].Rows[r][c].ToString();
                OUT += s;
            }
        }
    }
    return OUT;
}
```

if you want to convert one datatable into one string, you can omit the first `for`